# extjs nested data view select a node

Tags: select, extjs, nested, dataview, extjs3

i have data view with following tpl.

```
  <tpl for=".">
    <tpl for="departments">
                 {title}
    </tpl>
    <tpl for="records">
        <div class="thumb-wrap">
           {name}
        </div>
    </tpl>
</tpl>
```

and my json redear like this

```
        reader : new Ext.data.JsonReader(
         {
            root : 'data', 
         },
         [ 
            'departments' ,
            'records'
          ]
        ),
```

and my item selectore in on my recordes

```
itemSelector : 'div.thumb-wrap',
```

and this is my json data

```
{
"success": true,
"data": [
    {
        "departments": [
            {
                "title": "name"
            }
        ],
        "records": [
            {
                "name": "name"
            },
            {
                "name": "name"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "departments": [
            {
                "title": "name"
            }
        ],
        "records": [
            {
                "name": "name"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

how cat i select my **records** in data view with extjs?
and how can i get selected **recordes** ?
i used getSelectedRecords() but it return array of departments and records.
tnx

Comment: I'm gonna assume you are using ExtJS 4.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that [getSelectedRecords()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.view.AbstractView-method-getSelectedRecords) is deprecated on ExtJS 4.

You can try doing something like this:

```
var records = data.getRecords();
```

That will return a `Ext.data.Model[]`. Than, you can access all the properties like an usual model:

```
record.get('departments');
record.get('records');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are working against the system here with your record structure. DataView wants one record to correspond with one selectable item. But you want to have multiple selectable items inside one record. Doesn't work - the API was not designed for such a thing.

Your options seem to be:

- Create a separate DataView component for each set of records.
- Create your own DataView component that can handle grouping.
- Use Grid with GroupingView. You have to change your record structure to something like below, but it's the easiest option to get working. Though... you have to sacrifice quite a bit of flexibility offered by DataView.

  ```
  "data": [
      {
          {
              "department": "Department 1"
              "name": "record 1"
          },
          {
              "department": "Department 1"
              "name": "record 2"
          },
          {
              "department": "Department 2"
              "name": "record 1"
          },
          {
              "department": "Department 2"
              "name": "record 2"
          },
      ]
  }
  ```